# Advantage Java Long Suffix

Tags: java, literals

The Java Language specification (Section 3.10.1) states the following:

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l [...];
>   otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

So far so good, this means that the following two assignments will result in different results.

```
long x = 2_000_000_000 * 40_000;
long y = 2_000_000_000 * 40_000L;
```

So I see why the idea of having standardized Literal-Types makes sense, and why it's needed, but I can't really see the benefit of choosing `int` over `long` as the standard type for literals. 
After all, `long` would enable a broader amount of operations without the extra need to add specific suffixes as far as I can see.

If someone could explain the advantage to me, that would be of great help! 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's nicer, an occasional `L` or a lot of `(int)`?

Comment: Good point ! I didn't think of that in the first place !

Comment: Keep in mind that, in 1995, everybody had 32-bit machines and integers were a better, more performant default.

Answer (score 1):

`long` requires double the amount of memory required to store an `int`.
Keep in mind that Java runs on a lot of different devices, including memory-constrained embedded systems, mobile phones etc.

On a 32-bit machine, working with `long`s might be slower. Adding together two `int`s can be one CPU instruction, whereas adding two `long`s might require several.